# Design Pattern for Parsing LOGO Turtle Code

Tags: design-patterns, turtle-graphics, logo-lang

In wikipedia, Logo Programming is a multi-paradigm computer programming language used in education. I want to make an application like TurtleGraphicEditor (which using logo programing) using C#. I want each logo command act as method, example command "forward val" act as "forward(float val)", etc. What is design pattern that suitable for parsing the Logo code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very general question.  Here are some topics that you might want to read up on:

- lexers
- parsers (as you mentioned)
- abstract syntax trees
- compilers
- domain-specific languages
- interpreters

A general design for such an application might have two main components:

1. read text, lex and parse into abstract syntax tree
2. walk the syntax tree, either evaluating it or transforming it (compiling) into source code in a different language

But be warned!  This is not trivial!

Comment: Thanks for your help, it's very helpfull. I use command pattern but its very slow, because each method act as object. Seems like abstract syntax trees is interesting :)

Answer (score 0):

[Interpreter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreter_pattern) is ideal solution

Comment: yeah but that make the application more complex T.T, i've done it with normal parser function and use state, composite, and command pattern.